# iOS - Authentication with ldaps (iOSPorts)

Tags: ios

I've managed connecting iOS app with ldap, but I'm having tough time connecting to ldaps.

What worked for ldap was (short version).

```
LDAP *ld;
char *ldapuri = /* my uri with ldap:// */;
rc = ldap_initialize(&ld, ldapuri);
char *binddn = /* my dn info */;
char *password = /* my password */;
int version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version);
rc = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, binddn, password);
```

What I'm trying to do with ldaps (similar as in author's example):

```
LDAP *ld;
char *ldapuri = /* my uri with ldaps:// */;
const char *caFile = /* filepath to my cert */;
int err = ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, (void *)caFile); /* no error here */
rc = ldap_initialize(&ld, ldapuri);
char *binddn = /* my dn info */;
char *password = /* my password */;
int version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version);
rc = ldap_start_tls_s(ld, NULL, NULL); /* Here it fails */
```

With

```
ldap_get_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, (void*)&msg);
NSLog(@"   ldap_start_tls_s(): %s", ldap_err2string(rc));
NSLog(@"   ssl/tls: %s", msg);
```

I've managed to get these messages

> ldap_start_tls_s(): Can't contact LDAP server
>
> ssl/tls: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to authenticate with ldaps. It was a combination of previous two.

```
LDAP *ld;
char *ldapuri = /* my uri with ldaps:// */;
const char *caFile = /* filepath to my cert */;
int err = ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, (void *)caFile); /* no error here */
rc = ldap_initialize(&ld, ldapuri);
char *binddn = /* my dn info */;
char *password = /* my password */;
int version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version);
rc = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, binddn, password);
```